# Auth0 authentication with Next-Auth as identity provider?

Tags: saml, auth0, next-auth

I'm part of a small team as a nodeJS dev and I've been tasked into researching how this can be accomplished. I'm fairly new to OAuth and authentication so please bear with me.

Currently we have a next.js webapp that uses NextAuth for authentication with the user store in DynamoDB. What we want to do is provide an Oauth2 flow so a user can consent to a 3rd party service having access to their profile information via an endpoint. In this case we are the resource server, the 3rd party is the "client" and our user is the resource owner.

The piece of the puzzle I'm trying to put together is how does Auth0 work with NextAuth in this scenario? I want Auth0 to check if the user is logged in (otherwise prompting them to do so) via NextAuth, and for NextAuth to say "this is fine" and then for Auth0 to issue a token to the 3rd party (concluding a "normal" OAuth flow). Is this were SAML comes into play? I see there's a software package called SAML Jackson (lol) and there's a Next-auth integration for it.

Most examples I see usually work the other way around, with Auth0 as the identity provider, and what we're doing may be unique. Sorry if this question comes across as abstract but that's how it exists in my mind currently. Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect your user store to Auth0 as a [custom database connection](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/database-connections/custom-db/create-db-connection). And then create an application inside Auth0 and enable the DB connection for the app. This way Auth0 acts as the Authorization server for your client app.

NextAuth.js is just an authentication library that supports the OAuth2.0/OpenID protocols. The role of NextAuth is simply to initiate the authentication flow, take the user to the Identity Provider (in this case Auth0 backed by a custom user store) and finally process the authorization response from Auth0. The authorization response (code) is received at the application end and then exchanged for access_token and user profile (all handled by NextAuth.js).

And for your query on SAML, it's a standard for exchanging identity information between two parties an Identity Provider (IdP) and a service provider (SP). The same is achieved by its more modern counterparts OAuth2.0/OpenID Connect. Typically third-party apps which are deployed in an enterprise setting use SAML to integrate with on-premise Identity Management Systems like ActiveDirectory. You can read more about SAML on https://boxyhq.com/blog/understanding-saml-sso-the-basics-from-the-user-side.